# Segwit Taproot xPub switchup

Tags: segregated-witness, taproot, ledger-hardware-wallet, xpub, btcpay

I'm hoping someone can help me out here. I added a new wallet to my BTCPayServer, but I did not add "-[taproot]" to the end of the xPub. I assume that it then was perceived as a Segwit wallet, and the addresses generated was Segwit and not Taproot.

Basically I sent a transaction to one of the addresses not realizing my mistake, and now I have lost access to those Bitcoin, for what I hope is temporarily.

My question is, since it's the same xPub key used, wouldn't I be able to somehow use the private key to sign a transaction with that Segwit wallet to get the funds out?

I use a Ledger Nano S Plus.

I hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recover the funds by connecting my Ledger device to a third-party wallet Electrum. I set up a Native Segwit account but used a taproot derivation path to attempt the recovery.

Here are the steps I followed:

I went to Electrum.org and downloaded Electrum for my operating system.
Then, I opened the 'Set Up Electrum' guide on the site.
I navigated to the 'connect to Ledger' drop-down and followed steps 1-7.
At step 8, I selected 'Native Segwit' (but didn't click next yet).
I edited the derivation path below 'Native Segwit' to say 'm/86/0h/0h' (photo attached).
After following these steps, my balance was shown in the 'history' tab, and I was able to access and manage my funds from Electrum.